# Flex charts increase label size for category axis

Tags: apache-flex, charts, axis

I am using a column chart which has a horizontal axis for displaying dates.

Problem is when there are large data points then it shrinks the size of the label for the x-axis and i don't want this to happen.

I am displaying dates  in batches but still the label don't occupy the available space. The size of the label shrinks and the text is hardly readable.

Any suggestion on how i could increase the label size irrespective of the number of ticks.

Here is a snippet of my code.

Thank You.

```
  <mx:ColumnChart id = "areaChart"
                  height = "100%" 
                  width = "100%" 
                  seriesFilters="[]"                    
                  showDataTips="false"
                  type="overlaid"
                  columnWidthRatio="0.40"
                  mouseMove="showData(event)"
                  mouseSensitivity="600"
                  change="{callLater(showDefaultData)}"> 

       <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField = "date"
                             id = "hax"         
                             ticksBetweenLabels="true"
                             labelFunction="chartsLabel"/>
        </mx:horizontalAxis>

        <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer id="har" 
                             axis="{hax}"
                             textAlign="left"
                             tickPlacement="none"   
                             placement="bottom"                                                  
                             axisStroke="{Stroke}"/>


        </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a style for the `AxisRenderer` and use it in your definition:

Style:

```
<mx:Style>
    .axisStyle {
        fontSize:10;
        color:blue;
    }
</mx:Style>
```

Usage:

```
    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
       <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{axisName}" styleName="axisStyle"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis id="axisName" dataProvider="{dataProvider}" 
            categoryField="someCategory"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
```

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work when the data points increases.

Comment: Can you reapply it after the increase?

Answer (score 0):

You shall set

`canDropLabels="true|false"`

`canStagger="true|false"`

styles for chart's axisrenderer: it shall know what to do if there are too much text.

You can also set `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties for axisrenderer if you want to force removal of scaling. But you'll not need it unless you do something tricky.

You can also set `gutters` for chart and axisrenderer to provide extra space for drawing labels, but again, normally you will not need it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, teh CategoryAxis doesn't seem to have a renderer and therefore canDropLabels and canStagger cannot be set for it.